# Program to find Heat Index and Wind Chill (C Program)

Tags: c

I am having some trouble with the output of my program and can't figure out where I am going wrong. The Temperatures seem to be converting from celsius to Fahrenheit correctly, but when it comes to the the wind chill and heat index values, they are incorrect. This makes me think that something is wrong with the way I'm calculating them in my functions? If I could get an explanation to where my logic is wrong that would be great. Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor formatting!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define L_Limit -20
#define U_Limit 50
#define c1 -42.379
#define c2 2.04901523
#define c3 10.14333127
#define c4 -0.22475541
#define c5 -6.83783E-3
#define c6 -5.481717E-2
#define c7 1.22874E-3
#define c8 8.5282E-4
#define c9 -1.99E-6
#define d1 35.74
#define d2 0.6125
#define d3 35.75
#define d4 0.4275

double compute_heat_index(int num1, int num2);
double compute_wind_chill(int num1, int num2);

double compute_heat_index(int num1, int num2)
{
    int celsius;
    double humid=.40;
    double celsius_f=0, heat_index=0;
    int ext1=0;
    for(celsius=1;celsius<=num2;celsius++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", celsius);
        celsius_f=(celsius*(9/5))+32;
        printf("%2.2lf\t", celsius_f);

        for(humid=.40;humid<=1;humid=humid+.10)
        {
            heat_index=c1+(c2*celsius_f)+(c3*humid)+.   (c4*humid*celsius_f)+(c5*pow(celsius,2))+(c6*pow(humid,2))+(c7*pow(celsius,2)*humid)+(c8*celsius*pow(humid,2))+(c9*pow(celsius,2)*pow(humid,2));
            if(heat_index<80)
                printf("x\t");
            else
                printf("%2.2lf/t", heat_index);
        }
        if(celsius_f>100)
        {
            ext1++;
        }
        humid=.40;
        celsius_f=0;
        heat_index=0;
    }
    return heat_index;
}

double compute_wind_chill(int num1, int num2)
{
    int celsius, wind=5;
    double celsius_f=0, wind_chill=0;
    int ext2=0;
    for(celsius=1;celsius<=num2;celsius++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", celsius);
        celsius_f=(celsius*(9/5))+32;
        printf("%lf\t", celsius_f);

        for(wind=5;wind<=40;wind=wind+5)
        {
            wind_chill=d1+(d2*celsius_f)-(d3*wind)+(d4*celsius_f*wind);
            if(wind_chill>50)
                printf("x\t");
            else 
                printf("%lf\t", wind_chill);
        }
        if(celsius_f<-20)
        {
            ext2++;
        }
        wind=5;
        celsius_f=0;
        wind_chill=0;
    }
    return wind_chill;
}
int main(void)
{
    double num1, num2;
    int ext1=0, ext2=0;

    printf("Input a range of values using two numbers:\n");
    scanf("\n%lf%lf", &num1, &num2);

    while(num1<L_Limit&&num1>U_Limit&&num2<L_Limit&&num2<U_Limit)
    {
        printf("Range of Values are Invalid!\n");
        scanf("\n%lf%lf", &num1, &num2);
    }
  printf("Celsius\tFahrenheit\t5mph\t10mph\t15mph\t20mph\t25mph\t30mph\t35mph\t40mph\n");
    compute_wind_chill(num1, num2);
    printf("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d", ext1);
    compute_heat_index(num1, num2);
    printf("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d", ext2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `compute_wind_chill()` returns a value of type `double`. You are completely ignoring that value. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused what the return statement does. Wouldn't I want it to return the wind_chill I value I want?

Comment: It returns it but you haven't told `main()` to do anything with the return value. You probably meant `ext1=compute_wind_chill(num1, num2)`?

Answer (score 1):

While I make no comment on the correctness of your *stoichiometric calculations* (though I provide links and hints at the end), the following will help you find the problem, not only here, but hopefully in all future code you write as well. You are making things harder on yourself than they need be just by how you are formatting your code. Unless you are competing in a contest to see how few lines you can use, then for goodness sake, make things easier on yourself by *'opening up'* you code a bit. This will make it much easier for you, and anyone helping you, to follow the logic of your code and find logic errors. For example, it is almost impossible to spot logic errors in:

```
            heat_index=c1+(c2*celsius_f)+(c3*humid)+.   (c4*humid*celsius_f)+(c5*pow(celsius,2))+(c6*pow(humid,2))+(c7*pow(celsius,2)*humid)+(c8*celsius*pow(humid,2))+(c9*pow(celsius,2)*pow(humid,2));
```

(of course your compiler will loudly complain about the errouneous  `'.'` at the end of the first line)

It is much more readable written as:

```
            heat_index = c1 + (c2 * celsius_f) + (c3 * humid) +
                (c4 * humid * celsius_f) + (c5 * pow (celsius, 2)) +
                (c6 * pow (humid, 2)) + (c7 * pow (celsius, 2) * humid) +
                (c8 * celsius * pow (humid, 2)) +
                (c9 * pow (celsius, 2) * pow (humid, 2));
```

or even:

```
            heat_index = c1 + 
                        (c2 * celsius_f) + 
                        (c3 * humid) +
                        (c4 * humid * celsius_f) + 
                        (c5 * pow (celsius, 2)) +
                        (c6 * pow (humid, 2)) + 
                        (c7 * pow (celsius, 2) * humid) +
                        (c8 * celsius * pow (humid, 2)) +
                        (c9 * pow (celsius, 2) * pow (humid, 2));
```

**NOTE:** above you can easily see the misuse of `celsius` where `celsius_f` (Fahrenheit) should be used. Also note there is no need for `pow (celsius_f, 2)` where `celsius_f * celsius_f` will do the job.

Do the same for your output. Make it easy for you to read so it will be easier for others to read as well.

(I'm getting old and maybe your young-eyes have no trouble with code without spaces, it is much easier on me to help you if your code is adequately spaced and properly indented and your output looks like something other than spaghetti strung across the screen)

Avoid using **'magic numbers'** in your code, e.g.

```
    for(wind=5;wind<=40;wind=wind+5)
```

If you need constants in your code, declare them as required. That way, there is only one place you need to change the value, easily found at the top, instead of picking though your code to find them. You have declared a large number for your wet-bulb/dry-blub calculations, a few more for your limits is all that is required, e.g.

```
#define HMIN .40    /* define needed constants */
#define HMAX 1.0    /* avoid putting 'magic'   */
#define HSTEP 0.1   /* numbers in your code    */

#define WMIN 5
#define WMAX 40
#define WSTEP 5
...
    for (wind = WMIN; wind <= WMAX; wind = wind + WSTEP)
```

**Note:** your `HMIN, HMAX, HSTEP` values will change when you correct your units (see last paragraph).

It appears you are wanting to return the values of `ext1` and `ext2` from your `compute_wind_chill` and `compute_heat_index` functions. If so, then your function `type` should match your `return type` needed. If you are wanting to indicate whether a **extreme value** was encountered by returning `ext1` and `ext2`, then you should change your function type to `int` and assign the return to `ext1` and `ext2` in `main`, e.g.

```
int compute_heat_index (int num1, int num2);
int compute_wind_chill (int num1, int num2);
...
    ext1 = compute_wind_chill (num1, num2);
    printf ("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d\n", ext1);
    ...
    ext2 = compute_heat_index (num1, num2);
    printf ("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d\n", ext2);
```

Next, there is no need to make multiple calls to, e.g. `printf` when one will do. For example:

```
    printf("%d\t", celsius);
    celsius_f=(celsius*(9/5))+32;
    printf("%2.2lf\t", celsius_f);
```

can be easily replaced with a single `printf` call just by logically ordering your `celsius_f` calculation, e.g.

```
    celsius_f = (celsius * (9 / 5)) + 32;
    printf ("%d\t% .2lf\t", celsius, celsius_f);
```

Why you declare `num1` and `num2` as `double` in `main` is a complete mystery. You pass them as `int` to your functions (*where I assume `num1` is supposed to be the lower loop value for temp in the functions instead of the hardcoded `1` you have*). While you are free to allow users to enter e.g. `45.3` and read it as a `double`, and pass it as an `int`, it doesn't really make much logical sense. Here, the value of `45` is all that is ever used on your code. If you are reading as a `double` just to prevent error if a user enters `45.3`, then that is a legitimate reason, but why a user would rather enter `45.3` instead of just `45` is another matter...

Your limit testing for values less/greater than `L_Limit/U_Limit` is a bit *creative*. It is better to simply put the values in ascending order to simplify the test, e.g.

```
    /* VALIDATE all user input */
    if (scanf ("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (num1 > num2) {      /* get values in ascending order */
        double tmp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tmp;
    }

    while (num1 < L_Limit || num2 > U_Limit) {  /* simple test */
```

Formatting your output is just something that takes a little more attention to detail. While I'm no fan of tab (`'\t'`) formatting, I've made a quick attempt to clean things up a little to make the output more legible. Similarly, when you need an additional *newline character*, do not use the *variadic* `printf ("\n");`, there is no reason for the overhead just to output one character, use `putchar ('\n');` instead. (note: you don't make that mistake, but I had to add a *newline* so it was worth mentioning here).

When you compile your code, always compile with *warnings enabled*, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string. You can add `-pedantic` for a few additional checks and there are a multitude of additional individual checks you can impose. Above all, do not accept code until it compiles cleanly, without warnings. Read the warnings you get. The compilers are quite good now at explaining exactly where the problem is and what you are doing wrong. (you can learn a lot of C, just by listening to what your compiler is telling you).

You can compile your code with something similar to the following:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/windchill windchill.c
```

Finally, putting it altogether, you could reformat your code and incorporate the changes above into something like the following that should make finding your stoichiometric logic error much easier. I have put my additional thoughts in the comments below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define L_Limit -20
#define U_Limit 50
#define c1 -42.379
#define c2 2.04901523
#define c3 10.14333127
#define c4 -0.22475541
#define c5 -6.83783E-3
#define c6 -5.481717E-2
#define c7 1.22874E-3
#define c8 8.5282E-4
#define c9 -1.99E-6
#define d1 35.74
#define d2 0.6125
#define d3 35.75
#define d4 0.4275

#define HMIN .40    /* define needed constants */
#define HMAX 1.0    /* avoid putting 'magic'   */
#define HSTEP 0.1   /* number in your code     */

#define WMIN 5
#define WMAX 40
#define WSTEP 5

/* you only need prototypes if you do not define your functions
 * until AFTER the code that makes use of them. Moving the 
 * definitions AFTER main() makes the prototypes make sense,
 * otherwise, just omit them...
 */
int compute_heat_index (int num1, int num2);
int compute_wind_chill (int num1, int num2);

int main (void) {

    double num1 = L_Limit - 1.0,  /* num1 & num2 should be int */
           num2 = U_Limit + 1.0;
    int ext1 = 0, ext2 = 0;

    printf ("Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): ");

    /* VALIDATE all user input */
    if (scanf ("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (num1 > num2) {      /* get values in ascending order */
        double tmp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tmp;
    }

    while (num1 < L_Limit || num2 > U_Limit) {  /* simple test */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: values must be between %d - %d.\n",
                L_Limit, U_Limit);
        printf ("Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): ");
        if (scanf ("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* make the output format easy to read */
    printf ("\nDeg. C\t Deg. F\t 5mph\t 10mph\t 15mph\t"
            " 20mph\t 25mph\t 30mph\t 35mph\t 40mph\n");
    ext1 = compute_wind_chill (num1, num2);
    printf ("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d\n", ext1);

    printf ("\nDeg. C\t Deg. F\t 40%%\t 50%%\t 60%%\t"
            " 70%%\t 80%%\t 90%%\t 100%%\n");
    ext2 = compute_heat_index (num1, num2);
    printf ("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d\n", ext2);

    return 0;
}

/* comput and output heat index between num1 and num2 */
int compute_heat_index (int num1, int num2)
{
    int celsius, ext1 = 0;
    double humid = HMIN, celsius_f = 0, heat_index = 0;

    for (celsius = num1; celsius <= num2; celsius++) 
    {
        celsius_f = (celsius * (9 / 5)) + 32;
        printf ("%d\t% .2lf\t", celsius, celsius_f);

        for (humid = HMIN; humid <= HMAX; humid = humid + HSTEP) 
        {
            heat_index = c1 + (c2 * celsius_f) + (c3 * humid) +
                (c4 * humid * celsius_f) + (c5 * pow (celsius, 2)) +
                (c6 * pow (humid, 2)) + (c7 * pow (celsius, 2) * humid) +
                (c8 * celsius * pow (humid, 2)) +
                (c9 * pow (celsius, 2) * pow (humid, 2));

            if (heat_index < 80)
                printf ("x\t");
            else
                printf ("% .2lf\t", heat_index);
        }
        putchar ('\n');

        if (celsius_f > 100) {
            ext1++;
        }
    }

    return ext1;
}

/* comput and output wind chill between num1 and num2 */
int compute_wind_chill (int num1, int num2)
{
    int celsius, wind = WMIN, ext2 = 0;
    double celsius_f = 0, wind_chill = 0;

    for (celsius = num1; celsius <= num2; celsius++) 
    {
        celsius_f = (celsius * (9 / 5)) + 32;
        printf ("%d\t% .2lf\t", celsius, celsius_f);

        for (wind = WMIN; wind <= WMAX; wind = wind + WSTEP) 
        {
            wind_chill = d1 + (d2 * celsius_f) - (d3 * wind) + 
                        (d4 * celsius_f * wind);

            if (wind_chill > 50)
                printf (" x\t");
            else
                printf ("% .2lf\t", wind_chill);
        }
        putchar ('\n');

        if (celsius_f < -20) {
            ext2++;
        }
    }

    return ext2;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/windchill
Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): 45 55
error: values must be between -20 - 50.
Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): 45 50

Deg. C   Deg. F  5mph    10mph   15mph   20mph   25mph   30mph   35mph   40mph
45       77.00   x       x       40.41   26.25   12.09  -2.07   -16.23  -30.40
46       78.00   x       x       47.44   35.42   23.39   11.37  -0.66   -12.68
47       79.00   x       x       x       44.58   34.69   24.80   14.92   5.03
48       80.00   x       x       x       x       45.99   38.24   30.49   22.74
49       81.00   x       x       x       x       x       x       46.07   40.45
50       82.00   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x

Total Extreme Values: 0

Deg. C   Deg. F  40%     50%     60%     70%     80%     90%     100%
45       77.00   99.68   99.21   98.74   98.27   97.80   97.32   96.85
46       78.00   101.06  100.58  100.10  99.61   99.13   98.65   98.17
47       79.00   102.43  101.93  101.44  100.95  100.46  99.96   99.47
48       80.00   103.78  103.28  102.78  102.27  101.77  101.27  100.76
49       81.00   105.13  104.61  104.10  103.59  103.07  102.56  102.04
50       82.00   106.46  105.93  105.41  104.89  104.36  103.84  103.31

Total Extreme Values: 0
```

**note:** one glaring error is your *integer division* error in your conversion to Fahrenheit. You can remedy that by insuring *floating point* division of your conversion factor:

```
celsius_f = (celsius * (9.0 / 5)) + 32;
```

Making that one change will have a dramatic impact on your calculations, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/windchill
Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): 45 50

Deg. C   Deg. F  5mph    10mph   15mph   20mph   25mph   30mph   35mph   40mph
45       113.00  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
46       114.80  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
47       116.60  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
48       118.40  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
49       120.20  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
50       122.00  x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x

Total Extreme Values: 0

Deg. C   Deg. F  40%     50%     60%     70%     80%     90%     100%
45       113.00  170.20  168.93  167.65  166.37  165.09  163.81  162.53
46       114.80  173.15  171.84  170.54  169.23  167.92  166.61  165.30
47       116.60  176.09  174.75  173.42  172.08  170.74  169.40  168.06
48       118.40  179.01  177.65  176.28  174.92  173.55  172.18  170.81
49       120.20  181.92  180.53  179.14  177.74  176.35  174.95  173.56
50       122.00  184.82  183.40  181.98  180.55  179.13  177.71  176.28

Total Extreme Values: 0
```

You have some more work to do... You can start by reviewing [**The Heat Index Equation**](http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/heatindex_equation.shtml) (which appears to be where your constants come from -- but note you are missing the correction factors and you need to **pay careful attention** to the units of **humidity**). Then follow up by looking at [**Wind Chill**](https://www.weather.gov/media/epz/wxcalc/windChill.pdf) **paying careful attention** to the **exponent** on the *wind*. When you correct your formula, you will then need to *link* against the *math library*, so add `-lm` to your compile string. (that's little-`'L'`m). Once you correct your logic, you should see something similar to the following output.

(note: with the extreme values over a temperature range from `-20 to 50`, I get `164` wind_chill extremes and `332` heat_index extremes)

```
$ ./bin/windchill
Input a range of temps in deg. C, (e.g. t1 t2): 10 45

Wind Chill:

Deg. C   Deg. F  5mph    10mph   15mph   20mph   25mph   30mph   35mph   40mph
10       50.00   47.77   45.59   44.19   43.15   42.31   41.59   40.98   40.43
11       51.80   49.87   47.80   46.48   45.50   44.70   44.02   43.44   42.92
12       53.60   51.96   50.02   48.77   47.84   47.09   46.45   45.90   45.41
13       55.40   54.06   52.23   51.06   50.19   49.48   48.88   48.36   47.90
14       57.20   56.16   54.45   53.35   52.53   51.87   51.31   50.82   50.39
15       59.00   58.26   56.66   55.64   54.88   54.26   53.74   53.28   52.88
16       60.80   60.36   58.88   57.93   57.22   56.65   56.16   55.74   55.37
17       62.60   62.45   61.09   60.22   59.57   59.04   58.59   58.21   57.86
18       64.40   x       63.30   62.51   61.91   61.43   61.02   60.67   60.35
19       66.20   x       65.52   64.80   64.26   63.82   63.45   63.13   62.85
20       68.00   x       67.73   67.09   66.60   66.21   65.88   65.59   65.34
21       69.80   x       x       69.38   68.95   68.60   68.31   68.05   67.83
22       71.60   x       x       x       71.29   70.99   70.74   70.51   70.32
23       73.40   x       x       x       x       73.38   73.16   72.98   72.81
24       75.20   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
...

Total Extreme Values: 0

Heat Index:

Deg. C   Deg. F  40%     50%     60%     70%     80%     90%     100%
...
26       78.80   x       x       x       x       x       x       x
27       80.60   80.35   81.35   82.55   83.94   85.53   87.32   89.31
28       82.40   81.80   83.21   85.01   87.20   89.78   92.75   96.10
29       84.20   83.49   85.39   87.86   90.91   94.53   98.74   103.51
30       86.00   85.44   87.89   91.10   95.07   99.80   105.29  111.55
31       87.80   87.64   90.71   94.72   99.68   105.58  112.42  120.21
32       89.60   90.10   93.85   98.73   104.74  111.86  120.11  129.49
33       91.40   92.81   97.32   103.13  110.25  118.66  128.38  139.39
34       93.20   95.77   101.11  107.92  116.20  125.97  137.21  149.92
35       95.00   98.99   105.22  113.09  122.61  133.78  146.60  161.07
36       96.80   102.46  109.65  118.65  129.47  142.11  156.57  172.84
37       98.60   106.18  114.40  124.60  136.78  150.95  167.10  185.24
38       100.40  110.16  119.47  130.93  144.54  160.30  178.20  198.26
39       102.20  114.39  124.87  137.65  152.75  170.15  189.87  211.90
40       104.00  118.88  130.58  144.76  161.40  180.52  202.11  226.17
41       105.80  123.62  136.62  152.25  170.51  191.40  214.91  241.05
42       107.60  128.61  142.98  160.13  180.07  202.79  228.28  256.56
43       109.40  133.85  149.66  168.40  190.08  214.68  242.22  272.70
44       111.20  139.35  156.66  177.06  200.53  227.09  256.73  289.45
45       113.00  145.10  163.99  186.10  211.44  240.01  271.81  306.83

Total Extreme Values: 97
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is appreciated from a guy like me that is new to this! For the humidity, isn't the unit, percentage? Which will go into my calculations as multiplying by the decimal conversion. The wind chill exponent is .16, correct?

Comment: Yes and no, it wants the units in `percent` (e.g. `40` percent), that's why I hinted that `HMAX, HMIN, HSTEP` will change (by a factor of 100) `:)`, You are correct on the wind exponent `.16` so, `pow (wind, .16);`

Comment: You can cross-check the heat index values with [**Heat Index Calculator**](http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/heatindex.shtml). That's what I used to confirm the **'percent'** v. **'percentage'** unit issue `:)`

Comment: When you get your output correct, if you have any need to see the final code I used, edit your answer and post your updated code (AFTER your original question, don't delete your original code or the answers won't make sense)... and I'll post a link to what I used. (it is really just the code above with the calculation logic fixed and a couple of title lines for 'Wind Chill' and 'Heat Index' added.)

Comment: I'm still confused about the percent problem. I want them to go in as 40% or 50% values but be used in the function as .4 and .5?

Comment: im also confused as to how my extreme values are not coming out right. If the wind_chill is below 20 or heat_index is above 100 than I want ext to count it. In my outputs and your outputs, it seems to not be doing so correctly even though I changed the if statement to the appropriate variables instead of celsius_f.

Comment: In a range of `-20 -> 50`, I get `164` extreme `wind_chill` values and `332` extreme `heat_index` values. (hint: to test each value, move the `if` block inside the `for (humin...` and `for (wind...` blocks `:)`

Comment: In fact, if we want it for every value and not just the tested temperatures, I would update the `10 -> 45` degree output above as `Total Extreme Values: 97`. Let me know if you have any more problems. When you are done, you can compare with [**WindChill/Heat Index Example**](https://pastebin.com/ik5QPv6s). The link will remain for another 6-days.

Comment: On the *percent* issue, the difference is between *percent* and *fractional value*. The equation specifies humidity in *percent* `10, 20, 30, ...` not *fractional value* `.1, .2, .3, ...`. Why? I have no clue. Probably because the meteorologists are **not** engineers. It would drive me batty deriving an equation to use percent (why the heck multiply by a factor of 100 [unless you are avoiding floating-point]) And *wind* in mph? It always either 'ft/s', 'kts' or 'm/s'. But with weather the common civilian reference in the US is mph. So work was done to make a plug-in formula using that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have one final issue. The extreme value for the heat_index function is incorrect since the output is so large. I don't see where its going wrong since it works for the wind_chill function.

Comment: I found it. Since you only consider `heat_index` values `>= 80`, you need to move the `if (heat_index > 100)` inside the `else` block. (`temps <= 9` also cause `heat_index > 100` but you never see that because you output `x` for `celcius_f < 80`) So I've updated the code at the link I gave you. Basically you need `if (celcius_f < 80) ... else { printf (...) if (heat_index) > 100) ext1++; }`. The total extreme values for `heat_index` is now `132`.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
celsius_f=(celsius*(9/5))+32;
```

In C `9/5` is not equal to 9/5 as in real math, here integer divided by integer is equal to integer too, rounded to lower value. So here 9/5 is equal to 1, not 1.8. You should use `float` variable type, for example

```
celsius_f=(celsius*(9.0/5))+32;
```

Another mistake is here:

```
compute_wind_chill(num1, num2);
printf("\nTotal Extreme Values: %d", ext1);
```

You are displaying float result as integer.

Comment: but aren't ext1 and ext2 integer values since I set them as integers in the main and user defined functions? Could you elaborate please, I'm confused

Comment: Good on the diagnosis of the bad conversion from Fahrenheit to Centrigrade; not so good on the inaccurate diagnosis with `ext1`, `ext2`.  It isn't clear how those are supposed to change from 0, though.

Comment: I have the if statement that increments those values in the functions. Am I right in the implementation of the incrementation or no?